# Create Globally Unique ID in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a script that, when a user loads, creates a unique id. Which is then saved in `localStorage` and used for tracking transactions. Sort of like using a cookie, except since the browser is generating the unique id there might be collisions when sent to the server. Right now I'm using the following code:

```js
function genID() {
    return Math.random().toString(36).substr(2)
        + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2)
        + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2)
        + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2);
}
```

I realize this is a super basic implementation, and want some feedback on better ways to create a "more random" id that will prevent collisions on the server. Any ideas?

Comment: does javascript have GUID?

Comment: @SamIam phpjs, underscore, and i'm sure many more libraries have a uniqueId function, but JS does not provide one natively

Comment: @TrevNorris Were you actually running into conflicts with that? How many entries did you have?  I created a simple test to determine how many Math.random().toString(34).substr(2)'s it took to create a duplicate, and with web workers my script ran for a few hours without creating a conflict. (toString(36) is shorter and still has 7.30787211e+9 different permutations)

Comment: @SgtPooki I'd never run into a conflict. Just wanted to know if there was a Right Way to do uid's in JS.

Comment: @TrevNorris thanks for the confirmation, I wanted to make sure I didn't need to go back and fix something... =P

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've used this in the past. Collision odds should be very low.

```
var generateUid = function (separator) {
    /// <summary>
    ///    Creates a unique id for identification purposes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="separator" type="String" optional="true">
    /// The optional separator for grouping the generated segmants: default "-".    
    /// </param>

    var delim = separator || "-";

    function S4() {
        return (((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000) | 0).toString(16).substring(1);
    }

    return (S4() + S4() + delim + S4() + delim + S4() + delim + S4() + delim + S4() + S4() + S4());
};
```

Comment: I like the way you constrained the random value length.

Comment: @James South, I did not exactly get it..can you explain?

Comment: What does the '0x10000' do?

Comment: It's 65536, the largest 16bit number https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/65536_(number)

Comment: Little suggestion: I found others samples using a call to getTime() to limit the risks of collisions...

var generateUid = function (separator) {
    var delim = separator || "-";
    function S4() {
        return (((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000) | 0).toString(16).substring(1);
    }
var st = ((new Date).getTime().toString(16)).slice(0,11) + (((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000) | 0).toString(16).substring(1,2);

    return (S4() + S4() + delim + S4() + delim + S4() + delim + S4() + delim + st);
};

Comment: @JackNicholson 0x10000 = 65536

Comment: function random() {
  return btoa(
    JSON.stringify({
      time: Date.now(),
      uid: Math.round(Math.random() * 1000000000)
    })
  );
}

Comment: Using Arrows => https://stackoverflow.com/a/75855405/3057246